# Modal confirmation type and hook_form_alter in WebForm module

Tags: 8, webforms

I have a *_hook_form_alter for a form being submitted with the Webform module. The $form_id triggers one of a couple *_form_emails_form_submit functions

Using the inline confirmation message type (Webforms >> Setting >> Confirmation), I have no issues triggering the *_form_emails_form_submit function that handles it.

When I switched to use the modal confirmation I started getting errors that my $form_state->getValue('email_address') (One of my fields in the webform) was null and broke the functionality of the *_form_emails_form_submit function

For example:

```
    function my_module_form_emails_form_alter(&$form, FormStateInterface $form_state, $form_id) {
     //Switch statement that looks for form_id and fires off below
     foreach (array_keys($form['actions']) as $action) {
            if ($action != 'preview' && isset($form['actions'][$action]['#type']) && $form['actions'][$action]['#type'] === 'submit') {
              $form['actions'][$action]['#submit'][] = 'product_learn_more_form_emails_form_submit';
            }
          }
    }
    
    function product_learn_more_form_emails_form_submit(&$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
      //When confirmation is inline
      $email_address = $form_state->getValue('email_address'); 
      //me@me.com
    
      //When conformation type is modal
      $email_address = $form_state->getValue('email_address'); //null
    }
```

I am not sure what I am missing or why switching to modal changes thing but any hints you can give would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Try adding your custom submit function to the #submit array before the default submit. Replace the `$form['actions'][$action]['#submit'][] = ...` line with `array_unshift($form['actions']['submit']['#submit'], 'product_learn_more_form_emails_form_submit');`

Comment: I do have a switch with 3 other cases and the default. I didn't post the full switch statement since it and the function is working fine if I have the confirmation type as inline but breaks if I switch it to modal confirmation. Thats why it is weird to me.

Comment: Do the `array_unshift` code to all the other submits